BigQuery Linking Error: "Internal Error. Please try again later" when submitting Linking Setup
I'm trying to link my Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties to a BigQuery project. Previously, I've successfully linked one property to the BigQuery project.
Now, I have around 7 more GA4 properties to link to the SAME BigQuery project but I'm getting "Internal Error. Please try again later" when I click on the Submit button in Linking Setup.
I tried to link one GA4 property that has the following total estimated daily event volume to be exported:
0.01 / 1 million daily limit / 1 of 1 stream selected / No events excluded
I've checked the browser console and it's showing something like the format below (I masked the numbers to x):
"POST https://analytics.google.com/analytics/app/data/v2/admin/integrations/linklist?dataset=axxxxxxxpxxxxxxxxx&gamonitor=gafe&hl=en_US&state=app.admin.integrations.big-query 500 (Internal Server Error)"
Not sure where to check because the Internal error notification is quite generic. Anyone encountered the same and was able to find resolution to the issue?


I had the exact same experience, but it is working fine today. It must have been an unreported outage on Google's side.

I had the same error yesterday. I managed to link GA4 to BQ this morning following the standard procedure, which didn't work yesterday. I believe this was just some kind of outage on Google's integration service side.
So, the answer is if you're getting "Internal error, please try again later" followed by a 500 internal server error in the console, simply do what it says - try again later, which in this case was the next day.
